# selecting all fields prepared statements

Tags: php, sql, class, prepared-statement

Alright so I'm converting all my sql statements to prepared statements and I cannot seem to figure out why this doesn't return any data:

```
public function get_all_movies(){
  if($result = $this->link->prepare("SELECT id,type,name,description,cover,movie FROM movies")){
   $result->execute();
   $result->store_result();
   $result->bind_result($id,$type,$name,$description,$cover,$movie);
   if($result->num_rows !=0){
    $results = array();
    $result->fetch();
    $results['id'] = $id;
    $results['type'] = $type;
    $results['name'] = $name;
    $results['description'] = $description;
    $results['cover'] = $cover;
    $results['movie'] = $movie;
    return $results;
   }else {
       return array("error"=>"No-media-found");
   }
   $result->close();
  }
   }
```

Converting from:

```
public function getAllMovies(){
        if($result = $this->link->query("SELECT * FROM movies")){
            if($result->num_rows != 0){
                $movies = array();
                while($movie = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                    array_push($movies,$movie);
                }
                return $movies;
            }else{
                return array("error"=>"No media found");
            }
        }
    }
```

Any advise fellas?

Comment: add error-handling and print/log errors? $this->link->error (for prepare) and $result->error (for execute). This should help.

Answer (score 0):

For selecting all fields use `*` symbol:

```
$this->link->prepare("SELECT * FROM movies"))
```

or use prefix of table:

```
$this->link->prepare("SELECT m.* FROM movies AS m"))
```

Comment: You can't use the asterisk in a prepared statement.

Comment: Did you try? No problem with asterisks in prepared statements. It's standard SQL. If you belive otherwise, please provide an example or an error message.

Comment: @fiskfisk It just returns random letters not the actual items

Comment: @JasonBassett That's probably cause by the usage of store/bind_results, and not the prepared statement itself - or by using an string as an array. Fetch the row as an associative array and use that, instead of bind/store result. Since you doesn't say which API you use it's hard to say exactly what method to call.